# помогите решить проблему с расширением

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

расширение должно выделять три слова на любой странице когда там только написано выделять что-то одно все работает,но как только я пишу три значение оно перестаёт работать
 в контен скрипте у меня написан вот такой код

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace(/(Яблоко)/g,
    '<span class="red">Яблоко</span>');

document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace(/(Лимон)/g,
    '<span class="yellow">Лимон</span>');

document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.replace(/(Киви)/g,
    '<span class="green">Киви</span>');
```

класы css просто задают цвет заднего фона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в вашем примере перезаписывается текст и получается срабатывает только последний replace.

```js
var re = /Яблоко/gi;
var re2 = /Лимон/gi;
var re3 = /Киви/gi;
var str = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
str = str.replace(re, '<span class="red">Яблоко</span>');
 str = str.replace(re2, '<span class="yellow">Лимон</span>');
  str = str.replace(re3, '<span class="green">Киви</span>');
document.documentElement.innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.red {color:red;}
.yellow {color:yellow;}
.green {color:green;}
```

```html
я сегодня напишу код Яблоко, а потом пойду съем Лимон с Киви
```

Comment: спс чувак ты меня спас обожаю тебя)